# Getting length of a string in dataframe column index to assign to a variable

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing

I've got a data frame where I am trying to get the length of a string in the first index of a column, so that I can then assign that length to a variable to be used in conditional statements:

```
branch_contact_column_string_length = filtered_df['Branch Contact/Notes'].iloc[0].len()
```

E.g.

```
If branch_contact_column_string_length <= 7:
   do this action
```

But keep getting either the error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'len'**, or **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'**. These two errors are preventing me from getting the length and putting it into a variable.

Comment: `len()` takes a string as an argument, it is not an attribute of a string.

Comment: Couldn't you use `...iloc[0].str.len()`?

Comment: That wouldn't work either since I get the error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'** when trying that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
branch_contact_column_string_length = len(filtered_df['Branch Contact/Notes'].iloc[0])
```

`len()` is a function, not a method.